# sending this form to an email

Tags: php, forms

I'm having issues with understanding how to tell this particular form to send to an email. I see it is sending to a database. would I just add in a $to = $_POST['email@email.com']; Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also in the html (which is generated by a CMS) the form action = "#3" So i'm not even sure if this php file I found is the one I'm looking for. My brain is melting.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["submitted"])) {


    # ---------------------------------------------- SEND THE MAIL

    $mailAddress = $mailContact;
    $mailSubject = "From the Contact Form at " . $siteName;

    if (strstr($_REQUEST["email"], "@")) {
        $mailHead = "From: " . $_REQUEST["email"] . "\r\n";
    } else {
        $mailHead = "From: " . $mailContact . "\r\n";
    }

    $mailMsg = "";
    $mailMsg .= "The following information was submitted at " . $siteName . ":\n\n";
    $mailMsg .= "Name: " . $_REQUEST["gname"] . "\n";
    $mailMsg .= "Email: " . $_REQUEST["email"] . "\n";
    $mailMsg .= "Phone: " . $_REQUEST["phone"] . "\n\n";
    $mailMsg .= "Message:\n\n";
    $mailMsg .= $_REQUEST["msg"];

    $mailMsg = stripslashes($mailMsg);

    if ($useMail == "yes") {
        mail($mailAddress, $mailSubject, $mailMsg, $mailHead);
    }

    # ---------------------------------------------- WRITE TO DATA

    $SQL = "INSERT INTO " . $pfx . "Contact (ClientID, AddDate, AddTime, GName, Phone, Email, Message) VALUES (";
    $SQL .= $_REQUEST["clientid"] . ", '";
    $SQL .= WriteDate(StraightDate(localtime())) . "', '";
    $SQL .= GetTime(localtime()) . "', '";
    $SQL .= clean($_REQUEST["gname"]) . "', '";
    $SQL .= clean($_REQUEST["phone"]) . "', '";
    $SQL .= clean($_REQUEST["email"]) . "', '";
    $SQL .= clean($_REQUEST["msg"]) . "')";

    DoQuery1($SQL);

    # ------------------------------------------ SHOW CONFIRMATION

}

?><table width="350" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><span class="pageCopy">

    Thanks for taking the time to write to us. If your message requires 
    a response, someone at <?=$siteName?> will be in
    touch with you as soon as possible.

    <br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br>

</span></td></tr></table><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just at a glance it appears that you are setting your $mailAddress to $mailContact. The mail function follows mail('TO', 'Subject', 'Message', 'Head'). Therefore maybe you should try changing your mail to.

```
$to = $_POST['email@email.com'];

if ($useMail == "yes") {
    mail($to, $mailSubject, $mailMsg, $mailHead);
}
```

Comment: yay! that worked. thank you guys. And thanks for the link. I'm still a beginner to php, always looking to learn more.

Comment: @SarahNewman feel free to check the "answered" box next to the question, incase other people use your question for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The email functionality is here:

```
if ($useMail == "yes") {
    mail($mailAddress, $mailSubject, $mailMsg, $mailHead);
}
```

The first thing I'd check is that $useMail is set to "yes"

You'll get more info on the mail function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)